# Vector Iterators Casting

Tags: c++, vector, pointers, casting

Hey, In C++, I have a vector of type:

```
vector<BaseClass*> myVector;
```

In which, I insert (push_back) pointers of derived classes into it.

Now, I want to pop back its elements so I do this:

```
vector<ADlgcDev*>::iterator iter;

for (iter = myVector.rbegin(); iter != myVector.rend(); iter++)
{
 // but before I pop it, I need to shutdown it down
 // so I cast this
 // but this way, I'm unable to call the function
 (DerivedClass*(*iter))->Shutdown();

 myVector.pop_back();
}
```

but as mention in the comments before I pop it, I need to call its **Shutdown()** method and the cast is not working properly too. Any resolutions? or is impossible?

Comment: BTW, your loop is broken -- either leave your `for` loop unchanged and remove `myVector.pop_back()`, or leave that in and change to a `while` loop that examines the `back()` element each time as sbi suggests.

Comment: If you mentally go through the steps with an array of 10 items, you'll find that you only process the 1st 5, because by that time you have already deleted the last 5 with `pop_back()`.

Comment: To make matters worse: rbegin() and end() are used, so the behaviour will be undefined

Comment: About rbegin() and end(): that would not compile, since rbegin() is a reverse_iterator

Comment: That's just a typo, corrected!

Comment: @Manzoor: I missed the fact that you're using reverse iterators -- your loop should work fine, my apologies. But while it will almost certainly work for a `vector` (the standard is actually not 100% clear about invalidation of reverse iterators), it won't work for a `list`. I'd suggest replacing your `myVector.pop_back();` with a `myVector.clear();` once after the loop (or just let `myVector` fall out of scope) -- that will work for any STL container.

Comment: Is it vector<BaseClass*> or vector<ADlgcDev*>? Is one a typedef? A subclass?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
while (!myVector.empty())
{
  ((DerivedClass*)(myVector.back()))->Shutdown();
  myVector.pop_back();
}
```

Notes:

- You should probably use `dynamic_cast` instead of the hard cast. (If it's sure that there are only `DerivedClass` objects in the vector, why isn't it `std::vector<DerivedClass>`?)
- You should probably not have to cast at all, since `Shutdown()` should be declared in the base class.
- You should probably delete the objects, too, before you pop them off the vector. (But that might not be so.)
- You should probably use a smart pointer which calls `Shutdown()` (and `delete`, probably).

*Edit:* Using `std::vector<T>::clear()`, [as shown by markh44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372288/vector-iterators-casting/1372405#1372405) is probably better than the `pop_back()`.

Comment: Excellent advice, especially bullet #2. But stefaanv is right, constructor-style casts won't work for pointer types -- do as he suggests instead.

Comment: I do agree with the comments and I like the new loop

Comment: Even better -- get rid of `Shutdown()` altogether and put the functionality in the destructor (which must become `virtual` since you will be deleting a derived class via a base class pointer). Use a `vector<boost::smart_ptr<BaseClass> >` instead, and then you won't need to remember to do *anything!*

Comment: Thanks, I have added another pair of parentheses to the cast. It looks really ugly now (good, it's smelly anyway), but it's still hard to grep for (bad). I should use a checked `dynamic_cast` instead, but then I'd have to re-phrase my notes... I feel dirty, though. `:-)`

Comment: It's just an example and if you remove the '_', it could even compile ;)

Comment: @stefaanv: Thanks, I have no idea how that crept in.

Answer (score 2):

Could you make Shutdown a virtual function in BaseClass?  Then you wouldn't need a cast.

Also you'll probably have trouble removing items from a vector while iterating.  I'd do it like this:

```
vector<BaseClass*>::iterator iter;

for (iter = myVector.rbegin(); iter != myVector.rend(); iter++)
{
    (*iter)->Shutdown();
}
myVector.clear();
```

Edit: and another thing, ++iter is generally preferred over iter++.

Comment: I guess `rbegin()` vs. `end()` might give trouble, too. Using `clear()` is a very good idea, though.

Comment: @markh44: That's the problem. It was one of the problems with the original code.

Comment: @sbi that's ok then I thought I'd finally gone mad.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor casting doesn't work for pointers.  Use static_cast if you're sure or dynamic_cast and check.

Answer (score -1):

If Shutdown() is a virtual method of the Base class i.e. BaseClass::ShutDown() you should directly call iter->ShutDown();

Otherwise if the method isn't virtual you should use `dynamic_cast`.

```
vector<ADlgcDev*>::iterator iter;

for (iter = myVector.rbegin(); iter != myVector.end(); iter++)
{
 DerivedClassA* a = dynamic_cast<DerivedClassA*>( *iter ) ;
 if ( a ) a->ShutDownA();
 else
 {
 DerivedClassB* b = dynamic_cast<DerivedClassB*>(*iter);
 if ( b ) b->ShutDownB();
 // ... repeat for every class in hierarchy that might be in the vector.
 }
 myVector.pop_back();
}
```

Anyway you're probably leaking memory, unless ShutDown() deletes the object from itself (which is generally a bad idea ) or you're keeping duplicated pointers and deleting them elsewhere, which is another risky idea.

Comment: Have you looked at what `iter` is initialized with and what it is compared to? And which one would you choose so that the `myVector.pop_back()` doesn't wreak havoc with the iterator? And if there are _several_ derived classes having a `ShutDownX()` function, it should _very_ likely be a virtual function declared in the base class.

Comment: I was just making the minimal changes to his design. Of course it should be derived, and the whole loop could be written in two lines.