# Howto avoid copying when casting a vector<Derived*> to a vector<Base*>

Tags: c++, casting, copy, stdvector

Is there a way to avoid copying large vectors, when a function expects a vector with (pointer to) baseclass objects as input but I only have a vector of (pointers to) derived objects?

```
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

void doStuff(vector<Base*> &vec)
{
    //do stuff with vec objects
}

int main()
{
    vector<Derived*> fooDerived(1000000);

    vector<Base*> fooBase(fooDerived.begin(), fooDerived.end()); // how to avoid copying here?
    doStuff(fooBase);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vector Iterators Casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372288/vector-iterators-casting)

Comment: You can't avoid the copy if you must keep your `doStuff` function exactly as it is. If you're willing to change that function (say to a template that accepts an iterator range), then there may be a way.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Isn't your comment the *answer* to his question? If you'd make it the answer, it would get my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use a `vector<Derived*>` as if it where a `vector<Base*>`, you could add a pointer to a `class OtherDerived : public Base` to that vector. This would be dangerous.

Comment: you could _not_ add a `OtherDerived*` to a `vector<Derived*>`. I think you know, but the wording is very unclear. Also: what is the point of the answer?

Comment: Point of the answer is: you cannot avoid copying. Of course you cannot add a `OtherDerived*` to a `vector<Derived*>`. But if you avoid copying, the compiler does not know that it's a `vector<Derived*>` and thinks it's a `vector<Base*>` allowing you to slip in an `OtherDerived*` through the back door.

Comment: I see the point...
That means I'll have to rethink my design because I really don't want to copy the vector. :(

Comment: @Ben: How many elements do you have in the vector? What operations are going to be performed by the function? The cost of copying is probably minimal (i.e. `std::vector<base*> vb( bd.begin(), bd.end() );` in many implementations will trigger a single allocation and N copies of pointers (possibly offsetting the pointer as needed: consider an addition/substraction plus the copy). Now performance aside, if the function is to modify the vector then the problem is that you shouldn't as it will break type safety as @Oswald points out.

Comment: @David I might have millions of objects in the vector. And actually, the job of doStuff() is to add even more objects loaded from file. The Base and Derived class look exactly the same, that's why I have the file loading implemented in the base class. The only difference between Base and Derived is the way the objects are computed (e.g. GPU vs. CPU), but maybe Derived and Base should be the same class

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast the vectors. However, you shouldn't really need to either.

If you really want, you could use Boost Iterator ([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html#example))

```
static Derived* ToDerived(Base* b)
{
    return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b); // return null for incompatible subtypes
}

static void DoSomething(Derived* d)
{ 
          if (!d)
               return; // incompatible type or null entry
          // do work
}


// somewhere:
{
    std::vector<Base*> bases;

    std::for_each(
         boost::make_transform_iterator(bases.begin(), &ToDerived),
         boost::make_transform_iterator(bases.end(), &ToDerived),
         DoSomething);
}
```

**Note**: a particularly handy effect of using **[`dynamic_cast<Derived*>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast)** is that if the runtime type of the object cannot be casted to `Derived*` (e.g. because it is actually an `OtherDerived*`, it will simply return a `null` pointer.

Comment: OP does not want to downcast.

Comment: Ah good point. In which case I don't see what he is trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of `doStuff()` is absolutely mandatory, then you won't get around the copy. Containers of pointers aren't "covariant" with respect to the pointee's class hierarchy, for a whole host of reasons. (For example, if you could treat `vector<Derived*>` like a `vector<Base*>`, you could insert `Base`-pointers into it which wouldn't behave like `Derived`-pointers. In any event, the parameter type of a container is fixed and part of the container's type.)

If you do have some leeway with the function, you could restructure the code a bit: You could make it a template parametrized on the container, or a template on an iterator range, and/or you could split the actual workload into a separate function. For example:

```
void doStuffImpl(Base *);

template <typename Iter>
void doStuff(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  for (Iter it = begin; it != end; ++it)
  {
    doStuffImpl(*it);  // conversion happens here
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm... but I want to add objects to the vector. And actually, Base and Derived look exacly the same. The only difference is the way they are computed. But I don't really see yet, how to change my design... I guess I'll have to think of another question ;)

Comment: @Ben: You can also make the container type into a template parameter, rather than the iterator range.

Answer (score 0):

Since your template for the vector is a pointer, your fooBase local variable is going to be using reference. Maybe the question is not very clear, if you could specify clearly we may try to address the problem!

Comment: `the template` is not a pointer. You are _not_ going to use a reference (the _pointer_ is _copied by value_). Maybe the answer is not very clear!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store only pointers to the base class like this:

```
vector<Base*> v(100);
v.push_back(new Derived());

doStuff(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this topic](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/34099/) interesting where they mention you can safely cast `Derived*` to `Base*` (but not the other side) while this is not possible from `vector<Derived*>` to `vector<Base*>` but you kind of should be able to... (*Ok, the address of the vector changes, thus needing a copy*)
One dirty solution they mention is using `reinterpret_cast<vector<Base*> >(vector<Derived*>)` but not sure if it's better then using the copy constructor... probably the same thing happens.